# Setting dynamic properties with key from a private collection in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Running this in the http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground ...

```
interface TestObj {
  name:String;
}  
class Test {
  test;
  private myCollection:TestObj[] = [];
  private anyCollection:any[] = [];
  constructor() {
    var obj:any = {};
    var refObj = {name:'prop'};
    obj[refObj.name] = "This works!";

    var collection:any[] = [];
    collection.push(refObj);
    this.test[collection[0].name] = "This works!";

    this.myCollection.push(refObj);
    obj[this.anyCollection[0].name] = "This works!?";

    this.myCollection.push(refObj);
    obj[this.myCollection[0].name] = "What the deuce!?! this.myCollection[0].name is supposed to be a string! Am I not?";

    var newRefObj:TestObj = { name: 'prop' };
    this.myCollection.push(newRefObj);
    obj[this.myCollection[1].name] = "This doesn't work either.";
  }
}
```

I get this on the last part of the statement.

```
An index expression argument must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol, or 'any'.
(property) Test.myCollection: TestObj[]
```

I guess I might be having a hard time understanding "private" properties.  I have done crazy amounts of research but I seriously have a hard time understanding geek speak.  I can't seem to find anyone having this issue so I am presuming it's some sort of noob thing.

Ideally, I would rather like to show an error if I tried using myCollection from outside of the Test class.

Comment: My guess would be that TS does recognise that the first object in your collection does not have a `name` property - your "index expression argument" resolves to `undefined`. I guess you wanted to use `.push(refObj)`?

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code.  Still, getting the warning though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primitive type of a string is `string` and not `String`. Change the interface accordingly:

```
interface TestObj {
  name: string;
}
```

`String` is for the String object while `string` is for the primitive type. For example:

```
var obj: any = {};
var strObj = new String("test"); // typed as String
var str = "test";                // typed as string

obj[strObj] = "test";            // error you were seeing
obj[str] = "test";               // ok
```