# TypeScript: Cannot find name error when Referencing an Interface across multiple files

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create some definition files for a personal project. (I'm recreating the context here with different class/module names, so the modeling may not make a whole lot of sense).

I have the following interface definition file, that has no dependencies, and compiles fine:

```
// File: automobile.d.ts
declare module Transport {
    interface Automobile {
        // ... variables and functions
        accelerate(direction:String):Boolean;
    }
}
```

However, in this file, when I try to reference `Automobile` in this file within the same `Transport` module, I get a `Cannot find name 'Automobile'`.

```
// File: automobile_collection.d.ts
declare module Transport {
    interface AutomobileCollection {
        size:Number;
        getItemAt(index:Number): Automobile;
    }
}
```

I've tried exporting the interface, but that didn't help. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue in visual studio or with tsc 1.5-beta. How are you compiling this? By the way, you should use the primitive types `number`, `string`, `boolean` (lowercase) instead of the interfaces as using the interfaces can [lead to problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823705/setting-dynamic-properties-with-key-from-a-private-collection-in-typescript/30823922).

Comment: Interesting, I'm using Webstorm's Typescript plugin. I'll give tsc a shot and see if I still get errors. Maybe this is Webstorm intellisense problem. And, thanks, I had no idea about the primitive type thing. Will replace those too.

Comment: Wow okay thanks for the tip. My whole project compiles just fine using tsc. I guess it's a webstorm issue. At least this informs my Google searches more. Thanks!

Comment: Figured it out, and posted an answer to my own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188246/david-sherret), I figured out that it wasn't a compiler error, because my project compiles fine using `tsc`.

It turns out you need to add `/// <reference path="./automobile.d.ts"/>` at the top of `automobile_collection.d.ts` to get Webstorm to intelligently figure out referenced types.

Comment: Ah! Ok, that makes sense. I'm so used to not adding `/// <reference ... />` nowadays that this solution didn't occur to me. I guess Webstorm doesn't have the functionality that does that automatically yet.